# Why Thunderbird does not load profile?

Tags: thunderbird, email, .profile

I'm having a serious problem with Thunderbird.

Recently I started the program, but it did not load my profile. He opened asking to configure the e-mail as if it were the first time I was using the program.

I checked the folder. Thunderbird and the file "profile" the key "path" is set correctly for the profile file "exemplo.default".

Does anyone know how to fix it.

Otherwise, I'll lose all my important messages forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to reinstall the OS, so the Thunderbird is running fine again.

Answer (score 0):

start TB with profile manager in terminal:

> thunderbird -profilemanager

Then create a new profile. In next screen give a name to the new profile and locate the folder for the profile. From checking the selection box you can decide to start TB with profile selection or not.

You can actually make more than one profiles for backing up purposes.